# Syncing Google Calendar on Android 2.3.4 Gingerbread

Tags: sync, calendar, google-calendar

I've got an Android Gingerbread device. When I go to `Settings -> Accounts & Sync -> Manage Accounts (and click on my email address) -> Sync Calendar`, I see an exclamation mark besides the sync icon (the one with the two arrows forming a circle), and a message below the entry saying "! Sync is currently experiencing problems. It will be back shortly."

Why do I get this message? Can I get things to work by say, installing CyanogenMod? (I am using an LG P690 Optimus Net.) I've heard LG phones tend to have more bugs than other brands such as Samsung, is this true?

Comment: Optimus 4X (P880) here. I had the very same problem initially, and was asked to enter my password each time when I tried to sync manually (or install/update an app via playstore). According to "googling", it looks like a server error (but just for one of my devices? unlikely). It solved itself after a few network switches: Experienced this problem with WiFi at home, 3 days long. On day 3 I went outside, using mobile data. Returned home that evening (back in my Wifi), problem was gone. Never found out the real reason -- but you might try "switching networks" and see.

Comment: Seems like I might want to get a mobile 3G connection hooked up to my device so that I can try this out. I will follow your advice and see if that works.

Comment: Actually, I think there was a server error on that particular day or something. Now my Contacts have the same sync error but not the calendar.

Comment: Yeah, but the funny thing is: when I had the trouble with my Optimus, none of my other devices had any problems. All of them connected via the same WiFi router. So either LG has some "special server" configured (then all LG users should have the problem at the same time, but I luckily don't have any now), or it is device-specific trouble based on something else. I'm curious if the problem disappears for you as soon as you've switched to mobile data for a while (which is what I suspect).